# Google Calendar client for OS X

Tags: macos, google-calendar

Is there any client for OS X that works with Google Calendar and makes it more usable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Fantastical: http://flexibits.com/fantastical

or use iCal with CalDAV and Google Calendar: http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358#ical

Comment: Fantastical doesn't do anything without iCal being set up. Technically it's just an interface to iCal -- if you need to edit appointments or what not it punts you to iCal to do all of that. That being said: it is an awesome way to create appointments and see your iCal calendars at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable access to Google Calendar in iCal, which seems to work well:

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358#ical

Hopefully this will get you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Last time I checked, iCal with Google Calendar on CalDAV can get pretty ugly if you have multiple calendars. I vouch for two of [BusyMac Software's](http://www.busymac.com/) products: [BusySync](http://www.busymac.com/busysync/) is a tool to sync iCal with Google Calendar much more cleanly, and [BusyCal](http://www.busymac.com/busycal/) is an iCal clone with a bunch of extra useful features (I'd call it iCal Pro) and native Google Calendar syncing.

Comment: iCal with Google Calendar on CalDAV actually works pretty fine, only sometimes you have to move some events twice in iCal. Any other issues?

Answer (score 1):

I just use the Google Calendar web app in a Fluid window. I realize this isn't a native client, but I've tried iCal, BusyCal, and Fantastical, and non of these had a more usable and faster (i.e. keyboard shortcuts) interface than the Google Calendar web site.